# Reflecting sqlite database with spellfix1 tables

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to reflect a database (more specifically the [plex media server database](https://www.plex.tv/)) which is sqlite based.

I can connect to the DB:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session

from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.engine.reflection import Inspector

conn = 'sqlite:////..../com.plexapp.plugins.library.db-2016-07-17'
eng = sa.create_engine(conn)
plex = eng.connect()
```

I can query the DB:

```
s = create_session(plex)
r = s.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM METADATA_ITEMS')

r.fetchall()

>>> [(55368,)]
```

And I can even inspect all the tables with SQLAlchemy's Inspector

```
i = Inspector.from_engine(plex)
i.get_sorted_table_and_fkc_names()
>>>> [('metadata_item_views', set()),
 ('cloudsync_files', set()),
 ('library_timeline_entries', set()),
 ('synced_ancestor_items', set()),
 ('schema_migrations', set()),
 ('fts4_tag_titles_stat', set()),
 ('spellfix_tag_titles', set()),
 ('metadata_items', set()),
 ('media_streams', set()),
 ('metadata_relations', set()),
 ('play_queue_generators', set()),
 ...
```

However, I can't seem to reflect the entire DB. I'm getting this big ugly exception:

```
m = sa.MetaData(bind=plex)
m.reflect()
>>>>
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1138                         parameters,
-> 1139                         context)
   1140         except Exception as e:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    449     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 450         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    451 

OperationalError: no such module: spellfix1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-8cb90bbdb0ad> in <module>()
      1 m = sa.MetaData(bind=plex)
      2 
----> 3 m.reflect()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in reflect(self, bind, schema, views, only, extend_existing, autoload_replace, **dialect_kwargs)
   3653 
   3654             for name in load:
-> 3655                 Table(name, self, **reflect_opts)
   3656 
   3657     def append_ddl_listener(self, event_name, listener):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    414             except:
    415                 with util.safe_reraise():
--> 416                     metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
    417 
    418     @property

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     58             exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = self._exc_info
     59             self._exc_info = None   # remove potential circular references
---> 60             compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
     61         else:
     62             if not compat.py3k and self._exc_info and self._exc_info[1]:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    184         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    185             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 186         raise value
    187 
    188 else:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kw)
    409             metadata._add_table(name, schema, table)
    410             try:
--> 411                 table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
    412                 table.dispatch.after_parent_attach(table, metadata)
    413                 return table

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in _init(self, name, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    482         # circular foreign keys
    483         if autoload:
--> 484             self._autoload(metadata, autoload_with, include_columns)
    485 
    486         # initialize all the column, etc. objects.  done after reflection to

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py in _autoload(self, metadata, autoload_with, include_columns, exclude_columns)
    494             autoload_with.run_callable(
    495                 autoload_with.dialect.reflecttable,
--> 496                 self, include_columns, exclude_columns
    497             )
    498         else:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in run_callable(self, callable_, *args, **kwargs)
   1475 
   1476         """
-> 1477         return callable_(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1478 
   1479     def _run_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in reflecttable(self, connection, table, include_columns, exclude_columns)
    362             self, connection, table, include_columns, exclude_columns):
    363         insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(connection)
--> 364         return insp.reflecttable(table, include_columns, exclude_columns)
    365 
    366     def get_pk_constraint(self, conn, table_name, schema=None, **kw):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py in reflecttable(self, table, include_columns, exclude_columns)
    561 
    562         for col_d in self.get_columns(
--> 563                 table_name, schema, **table.dialect_kwargs):
    564             found_table = True
    565 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py in get_columns(self, table_name, schema, **kw)
    367         col_defs = self.dialect.get_columns(self.bind, table_name, schema,
    368                                             info_cache=self.info_cache,
--> 369                                             **kw)
    370         for col_def in col_defs:
    371             # make this easy and only return instances for coltype

<string> in get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema, **kw)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py in cache(fn, self, con, *args, **kw)
     52     ret = info_cache.get(key)
     53     if ret is None:
---> 54         ret = fn(self, con, *args, **kw)
     55         info_cache[key] = ret
     56     return ret

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py in get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema, **kw)
   1181     def get_columns(self, connection, table_name, schema=None, **kw):
   1182         info = self._get_table_pragma(
-> 1183             connection, "table_info", table_name, schema=schema)
   1184 
   1185         columns = []

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py in _get_table_pragma(self, connection, pragma, table_name, schema)
   1478         qtable = quote(table_name)
   1479         statement = "%s%s(%s)" % (statement, pragma, qtable)
-> 1480         cursor = connection.execute(statement)
   1481         if not cursor._soft_closed:
   1482             # work around SQLite issue whereby cursor.description

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    904         """
    905         if isinstance(object, util.string_types[0]):
--> 906             return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
    907         try:
    908             meth = object._execute_on_connection

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_text(self, statement, multiparams, params)
   1052             statement,
   1053             parameters,
-> 1054             statement, parameters
   1055         )
   1056         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1144                 parameters,
   1145                 cursor,
-> 1146                 context)
   1147 
   1148         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1339                 util.raise_from_cause(
   1340                     sqlalchemy_exception,
-> 1341                     exc_info
   1342                 )
   1343             else:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
    200     exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = exc_info
    201     cause = exc_value if exc_value is not exception else None
--> 202     reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
    203 
    204 if py3k:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    183             value.__cause__ = cause
    184         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 185             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    186         raise value
    187 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1137                         statement,
   1138                         parameters,
-> 1139                         context)
   1140         except Exception as e:
   1141             self._handle_dbapi_exception(

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    448 
    449     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 450         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    451 
    452     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such module: spellfix1 [SQL: 'PRAGMA table_info("spellfix_metadata_titles")']
```

I understand that [spellfix1](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) is a feature of sqlite. But I couldn't find any python support/plugin to properly reflect it, or I don't fully understand the exception raised.

1. I'd love an explanation on **why** this is happening (why are these
   tables special and cannot be reflected normally?)
2. Is there any library/extension so that sqlalchemy could support this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a nice workaround.

SQLAlchemy allows metadata reflection to provide a callable for the 'only' flag.
This would ignore the unsupported tables that require the plugin. (thanks @CL. for the hint of ignoring those!)

```
m = sa.MetaData(plex)
m.reflect(only=(lambda x, y: 'spellfix' not in x))
Base = automap_base(metadata=m)
Base.prepare(plex)
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is an embedded database, and can be customized.
The Plex Media Server has added the spellfix1 extension; the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html) says:

> The spellfix1 virtual table is not included in the SQLite amalgamation and is not a part of any standard SQLite build. It is a [loadable extension](http://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html).

To be able to access this table, you'd have to compile this extension yourself, and load it into the Python database connection.

---

If you don't actually need to do spell checks, you can create a copy of the database without that virtual table:

1. convert the database to text with the `sqlite3` command-line shell:

   ```
   sqlite3 some/where/...library.db ".dump" > library.sql
   ```

   (this works without the module installed);
2. remove the creation of the virtual table from the SQL script; it's a line looking like this:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO sqlite_master(type,name,tbl_name,rootpage,sql)VALUES('table','xxx','xxx',0,'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE xxx using spellfix1(...)');
   ```
3. create a new database from that script:

   ```
   sqlite3 new.db < library.sql
   ```

Comment: This is pretty cool! is there any way for inplace modification with SQLAlchemy?